# $C([0,1], \ell_p)$ has a copy of $\ell_q$?

Tags: banach-spaces, lp-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

By Banach-Mazur theorem [ every separable Banach space X is isomorphic to a subspace of $C(0,1)$ ] we have that $C([0,1])$ has a copy of $\ell_p$.

But, $C([0,1], \ell_p)$ has a copy of $\ell_q$, where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$?

Comment: $C([0,1],\ell_p)$ has a copy of $C([0,1])$.

Comment: Thanks for help!